# How to load multiple UIView on single viewcontroller in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, objective-c++

I have more than 30 UIViews in one view controller called main view controller which are contains of Images and functionality added like pinch,rotate,pan gestures on UIImageView

I have got all the images using ALAssetsLibrary.

All Views works on this way, if user selected one pic than all one pic contains of UIViews open in menu option.

If user select two pics than all two pics contains of UIViews open. Same like all for 3,4,5 etc... See below image.

Currently I created all UIView's Outlet to Main ViewController.
Stored allUIView's objects in array and presented one by one on click with array index.
i also removed previous view when moving on second view but still memory increased.

So how can i release memory? So any other way to load multiple view on single viewController?

here I attach image,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuFc1.png)

Comment: Thats one of the reasons why you use multiple viewcontrollers and not a single one.

Comment: "below image" missing

Comment: I am not using multiple viewcontrollers. i have 30 UIViews. all of the views loaded on single viewcontrollers. one by one presented on click event.

Comment: By adding childrens

Answer (score 1):

You can use [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/) for loading N number of UIViews in single View Controller

Comment: it's not small view. all of the views have some functionalities like frames,gestures and textviews on it. it's also presented in full screen.

Comment: Are you memory warning this on Simulator or device

Comment: as i uses application, memory are increased, than after some time app crashed in device

Comment: did you checked with crash log

Comment: its not printed any crash log, as I used  All crash Exception  to fined crash position.